# User right problem while python script and git during boot up

Tags: python, git

I'm running a Raspberry that executes on the startup from the `rc.local` the following command:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/skript.py >> log.txt 2>&1 &
```

I need the sudo rights because the script is manipulating a lot of stuff. When the raspberry is shutdown via a button and the script, the git is called to see if there is an update:

```
from sh import git

git("--git dir=" self.gitDir + ".git/" ...)
```

The problem is, that I'm not able to submit the credentials for the remote repository hosted on Bitbucket. For the user `pi` I created a `~/.netrc` file as mentioned here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/permanently-authenticating-with-git-repositories-776639846.html

With the user `pi` it' s working, but the script is run by `sudo` and `sudo` is not able to use the credentials from the home directory of `pi`. I did not find an option to run the `git` command form `sh` with something like `-H -u pi`.

Maybe there is an option to give `sudo` a `~/.netrc` as well, but that I already tried without success. Maybe there is something special to know?

Answer (score 1):

Anything run from rc.local will be run with root permissions so the use of `sudo` is **redundant**.

To run part of the script as another user use the `su` command.  In particular use the form

`su - pi -c "command you want to execute as the pi user"`

Comment: The problem is that I don't run the `git`command out of `rc.loca`, I run it out of python and there it's not possible to pass `su -pi -c`.

Comment: Start your Python with that invocation.

Answer (score 0):

I found finally a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506124/how-to-enter-command-with-password-for-git-pull. I put the information to the `.git/config` file. Now `sudo` can access the repository also with credentials.